# MsVc++ weird error: not declared variable

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

The compiler is rising this error:

> 1>....\server\sv_init.c(528): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
> 1>....\server\sv_init.c(529): error C2065: 'v' : undeclared identifier
>
> ...(all instruction lines containing v)

here is a portion of the code :

```
while(shl>=7) {  
      shl-=7;
      int v = (sh>>shl)&127;// <-- Error is here 
      if (v==0 || v=='"' || v=='%' || v=='@') {
            tmp[ol++] = '@';
            //    Com_Printf("OUT:%02X\n",tmp[ol-1]);
            if (ol==sizeof(tmp)-1) {
                tmp[ol]=0;
                if (csnr==PURE_COMPRESS_NUMCS) {
                    Com_Printf(err_chunk);
                    return 1;
                }
            SV_SetConfigstring( MAX_CONFIGSTRINGS-PURE_COMPRESS_NUMCS+csnr, tmp);
            csnr++;
            ol=0;
            }
            tmp[ol++] = v+1;
        } else {
                tmp[ol++] = v;
        }
```

I tried to remove the line before the error line the code build fine, any help or suggestion would be thankfully welcomed.

Comment: _"I don't really know if it is a bug in Ms Visual Studio 2010 compiler"_ That's always the most unlikely thing to assume.

Comment: so what is it then ?

Comment: I wonder why people put a minus even before looking into a question, this is just mean

Comment: Yeah, they are almost as bad as people posting debugging questions without a MCVE.

Comment: Presumably it is due to something in the translation unit before the portion you included in your post. You'll have to do some work to narrow it down. If you can't spot it by looking over the code, you may have to try a divide-and-conquer approach. Good Luck.

Comment: @AviBerger thank you I'll try to reanalyze the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is being compiled in C mode (since the file has a .c extension). In C mode you can't declare variables after statements. You have three options:

- Change the code to declare variables at the start of the enclosing scope like this:

> ```
> while(shl>=7) {
>     int v; // declaration
>     shl-=7;
>     v = (sh>>shl)&127;
> ```

This may be a lot of work if there is a lot of code like this.

- Compile in C++ mode by changing the file extension to .cpp or specifying the /TP option. This may work because C++ is mostly a superset of C, but there a few C constructs that C++ doesn't allow.
- Use a different compiler that does support this feature in C, such as GCC.

Comment: I already compiled it with GCC it worked fine, this was very helpful thanks a lot

Comment: I moved the v variable to the top, well this isn't what I wanted but finally build

Comment: You also can just add an inner block with `{` and `}` that encloses the variable declaration and all statements that use it..